# Does bounded and continuous implies Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, functions, bounded-variation

If a function $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is integrable, bounded and continuous, is it also Lipschitz continuous?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. Let 
$$
f(x)=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
0&, x\leq 0\\
\sqrt{x} &,x\in [0,1]\\
-x^2+2x &, x\in [1,2]\\
0&, x\geq 2.
\end{array}\right.
$$
$f$ is continuous, bounded and integrable, but it is not Lipschitz, since $f|_{[0,1]}$ is not Lipschitz.

Comment: It's not integrable. To make it integrable, put $f(x)=\max(0,2-x)$ for $x>1$.

Comment: @tomasz, thanks and fixed!